# Накладываются компоненты при использовании react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Я начал осваивать react router, хочу сделать переход с окна регистрации на окно авторизации. Вроде как переход сделал, но появилась проблема с наложением компонентов друг на друга при нажатии на кнопку "Регистрация" (причем, url меняется):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

````
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Authorization from "./authorization";

import "./modal-form.css"

export default class Registration extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <Form className="modal-form">
                    <p className="label">Регистрация</p>
                    <Form.Control 
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Имя"/>
                    <Form.Control
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Фамилия"/>
                    <Form.Control
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Отчество"/>
                    <Form.Control
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Login"/>
                    <Form.Control
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="E-mail"/>
                    <Form.Control
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Пароль"/>
                    <Form.Control
                        className="modal-form__item"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Подтвердите пароль"/>

                    <Button  
                        variant="success"
                        className="button"
                        href="/authorization"
                        >
                            Регистрация
                    </Button>
                </Form>

                <Router>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path="/authorization" element={ <Authorization/> }/>
                    </Routes>
                </Router>
            </>
        )
    }
}```
````